# How can I clear OneSignal notifications using the OneSignal Flutter SDK?

Tags: flutter, notifications, onesignal

There does not seem to exist any method to clear notifications when using the OneSignal Flutter SDK.  I see the methods for other OneSignal SDKs, but not for Flutter.

For example, the Native Android SDK, and the Native IOS SDK, and the Cordova SDK has the method "clearOneSignalNotifications", but this method seems to be missing from the Flutter SDK.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: No solution yet?

Comment: No, I never found one.  I just let the users clear the notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I use this version 5.0.4

```
Future<void> removeOneSignalNotification() async {
  try {
     await OneSignal.Notifications.clearAll();
  } catch (_) {}
}
```

and it's working

source : [OneSignal GITHUB](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/blob/5.0.4/lib/src/notifications.dart)